# Qt or EFL for multi-platform Python application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

When chatting in IRC yesterday about the possibility to use P(C)ython instead of D for multi-platform GUI application, someone suggested me Enlightenment Foundation Libraries (EFL).

We have researched a bit about it and considering we would like to target some mobile-platform in the future as well, EFL looks as nice alternative to Qt.

So, what do you think how does EFL (used via Python bindings) compare with Qt (pyqt or pyside, depending on py3k readiness) for multi-platform desktop GUI application?

Comment: pyqt is py3k ready.  I'm commenting because I can't say anything on EFL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EFL looks good and promising, especially its widget toolkit which can do very smart things when resizing windows, but there are problems with it: first, it comes in a very-beta quality. Second, the widgets will look quite unfamiliar for the users. Qt is mature and stable, and it adapts to the platform look and feel (but still may be easily customized). I give PyQt a go.

Comment: "Qt is mature and stable" - I believe this is very important issue. I left Haskell and went to D, but now I see its eco-system is not mature enought although language is quite nice, so I would like not to repeat the mistake and choose nice toolkit like EFL over one which is stable & mature with plenty of docs, tutorials, books, tools...